# Australian visa requirement for a USA green card holder

Tags: visas, paperwork, australia, iranian-citizens

What kind of visa do I need to visit Australia from USA? I am a USA green card holder with an Iranian passport.

Answer (score 2):

You need to register for [class 600 status](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/visitor-600/tourist-stream-overseas), which costs at least AUD 140.

The status can be granted for 3-12 months.